# Facing the following error when importing Charts in React : SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, import, frontend

I am facing the error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
I don't know what is wrong with the import. The documentation also says to do like this.

The code where I'm facing the issue

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as ChartJS from 'chart.js';
import { Bar, Line, getElementAtEvent } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import registerChartComponents from './chartUtils';

const Charts = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    registerChartComponents();
  }, []);

  const { type, labels, datasets, options, width, height, setSelectedDataPoint } = props;
  const chartRef = useRef();
  const data = {
    labels,
    datasets
  };

  const printElementAtEvent = (element) => {
    if (!element.length) return;

    const { index } = element[0];

    setSelectedDataPoint(data.labels[index]);
  };

  const onClick = (event) => {
    const { current: chart } = chartRef;

    if (!chart) {
      return;
    }

    printElementAtEvent(getElementAtEvent(chart, event));
  };

  if (type === 'bar') {
    ChartJS.register(
      ChartJS.CategoryScale,
      ChartJS.LinearScale,
      ChartJS.BarElement,
      ChartJS.Title,
      ChartJS.Tooltip,
      ChartJS.Legend
    );
  } else if (type === 'line') {
    ChartJS.register(
      ChartJS.CategoryScale,
      ChartJS.LinearScale,
      ChartJS.BarElement,
      ChartJS.Title,
      ChartJS.Tooltip,
      ChartJS.Legend
    );
  }

  const customOptions = {
    ...options
  };

  if (type === 'bar') {
    return <Bar options={customOptions} data={data} width={width} height={height} />;
  }

  // if type is line
  return (
    <Line
      ref={chartRef}
      options={customOptions}
      data={data}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      onClick={onClick}
    />
  );
};

Charts.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  labels: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  datasets: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})).isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  setSelectedDataPoint: PropTypes.func,
  width: PropTypes.number,
  height: PropTypes.number
};

Charts.defaultProps = {
  width: 5,
  height: 400,
  setSelectedDataPoint: () => {}
};

export default Charts;
```

The error being shown -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5dc4.png)

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
  1 | import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
  2 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
> 3 | import * as ChartJS from 'chart.js';
    | ^
  4 | import { Bar, Line, getElementAtEvent } from 'react-chartjs-2';
  5 | import registerChartComponents from './chartUtils';
  6 |
```

Please help me as to why I am facing this error and how do I fix this?

Comment: try `import Charts from 'chart.js';`

Comment: Tried. Not working.